# Selecting DataTemplate from Window Resource in ViewModel with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a View where a small part of the window that displays the details of the item a user clicks on.  The format of these details changes, so my original implementation had a hide/show logic for the different kinds of items:

```
<Grid Name="Details1" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBox Name="Details_Field1" />
</Grid>
<Grid Name="Details2" Visibility="Visible">
    <TextBox Name="Details_Field2" />
    <TextBox Name="Details_Field3" />
</Grid>
<Grid Name="Details3" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBox Name="Details_Field4" />
    <TextBox Name="Details_Field5" />
    <DataGrid Name="Details_DataGrid1 />
</Grid>
```

Now, I want to make this 'less bad'.  My strategy was to make each of these Grids it's own DataTemplate, and manage state like so:

**View:**

```
<Window.Resource>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Details_Template1>
        <Grid Name="Details1">
            <TextBox Name="Details_Field1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Details_Template2>
        <Grid Name="Details2">
            <TextBox Name="Details_Field2" />
            <TextBox Name="Details_Field3" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Details_Template3>
        <Grid Name="Details3">
            <TextBox Name="Details_Field4" />
            <TextBox Name="Details_Field5" />
            <DataGrid Name="Details_DataGrid1 />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

....

<Grid Name="DetailsGoHere">
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding DetailsDisplay}" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    private DataTemplate _detailsDisplay;
    public DataTemplate DetailsDisplay
    {
        get => _detailsDisplay;
        private set => RaisePropertyChangedEvent(ref _detailsDisplay, value);
    }

....

private void Item_OnClick()
{
    // Pseudocode!  How do I reference Details_Template1 as a resource?
    DetailsDisplay = MyView.Details_Template1;
}
```

As the comment implies, I'm not sure how to reference the DataTemplates in my Window.Resource block from my ViewModel, so my question is twofold:

**1:  Is this a good solution to this kind of a problem?**

**2:  If so, how do I reference an item from my Window.Resource block in my ViewModel?**

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplateSelector` are used to switch DataTemplate in WPF.

Kindly refer this link http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html for detailed implementation.

PropertyDataTemplateSelector-

```
public class PropertyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
public DataTemplate DefaultnDataTemplate { get; set; }
public DataTemplate BooleanDataTemplate { get; set; }
public DataTemplate EnumDataTemplate { get; set; }

public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
           DependencyObject container)
{
    DependencyPropertyInfo dpi = item as DependencyPropertyInfo;
    if (dpi.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        return BooleanDataTemplate;
    }
    if (dpi.PropertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        return EnumDataTemplate;
    }

    return DefaultnDataTemplate;
   }
}
```

View -

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplates.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:DataTemplates"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Default DataTemplate -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
       ...
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate for Booleans -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanDataTemplate">
       ...
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate for Enums -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumDataTemplate">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->
    <l:PropertyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultnDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          BooleanDataTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanDataTemplate}" 
          EnumDataTemplate="{StaticResource EnumDataTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```